# ElasticSearch - Use results of one query as a filter for another

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm trying to convert to t-sql query to elastic dsl. 
I have 2 tables and I'm trying to fetch the data from second table by filtering with the selected guids from first query.

```
SELECT distinct guid INTO #temp                 
FROM table1                  
WHERE code =  13                                    
AND DateDiff(day, log_time, '2019-08-24') = 0                          

SELECT details,CreatedDate,guid
FROM table2           
WHERE guid IN (SELECT guid FROM #temp)          
ORDER BY CreatedDate desc,guid
```

I have tried to convert the first query on index1 in elastic dsl:

```
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "filter": [ 
        { "term":  { "code": 13  }},
        { "range": { "log_time": { "gt" : "2019-08-23 23:59:59.99",
                "lte" :  "2019-08-24 23:59:59.99"}}} 
      ]
    }
  },
   "_source": {
        "includes": ["_id", "guid"],
        "excludes": []
    }
}
```

Now I want to use the guids return by this query as a filter in second query on index2.
Is this possible in elasticsearch?
I know a join is not supported in elasticsearch. But is there any way to perform a subquery in elasticsearch?

I have looked into [terms lookup](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html#query-dsl-terms-lookup) but it seems this only works on _id of the document.
But in my case the guid which is the unique identifier in sql-server would just be a document property in elasticasearch.

Is there a way to tweak terms lookup to work on a field other than _id?

Comment: Terms lookup doesn't only work on the _id field, it can work on any field of your document that contains terms. However, since you have multiple conditions (code = 13 + date diff), I don't think terms lookup will cut it, indeed.

Comment: Is there any other way then to perform a subquery?

Comment: No, you can always do it in two queries, it shouldn't take much more time

Comment: @Val but what if result of first query is so big that fetching it in the consuming application and then sending it to the next query would result in huge network traffic?  would it be a good option?

Comment: Then, I'd suggest you rethink your data design. You probably need to better denormalize your data.

Comment: Also worth noting that coming up in 7.5 a new [enrich processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/ingest-enriching-data.html) will provide basic index-time JOIN capability.

Comment: wow this seems promising. Thanks a lot for the link!