# How to sort by aggregate from another index/type

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

i have a webshop and need to sort by the aggregate sales data. Example documents for products:

```
{
    "id": 123,
    "title": "foo product",
    "picture": "https://i.picsum.photos/id/959/200/300.jpghttps://i.picsum.photos/id/959/200/300.jpg"
}
```

Example documents for sales:

```
{
    "product_id": 123,
    "date": "2020-01-01",
    "sales": 5
},
{
    "product_id": 123,
    "date": "2020-01-02",
    "sales": 6
},
{
    "product_id": 123,
    "date": "2020-01-03",
    "sales": 2
},
{
    "product_id": 123,
    "date": "2020-01-05",
    "sales": 88
}
```

Please note, that days without any sales are not in the `sales` index/type.

Now:

- I need to filter all products that have more/less than X sales in a user defined time period (and even able to filter sales = 0)
- I need to sort asc/desc based on the sales in that time period (ascending would also mean that it should start with the products without sales).
- I need the matching product doc also in that result
- I should also be able to sort on other fields from the product index

How do i go ahead and do this? My background is from Solr and i would use streaming expressions for this.

**UPDATE**

I'm going to put a bounty on this. I found out that this could be achievable by using [Aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html) and nest them.

If my data structure has to be different for this, please describe. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need product information also after sorting or only Id is enough. I suggest you to try something and add that too in the post to avoid down votes

Comment: Yes, i would need this data as well. Edited the original question. Thanks :)

Comment: Did you get a chance to try the below update?

Comment: Hi @Gibbs, unfortunately it doesn't help with the "filter with 0 sales" or "sort by sales asc starting with 0 sales" thing although i do really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3):

Joining two indices is not possible in elasticsearch.

There are couple of options:

1. [Join type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/parent-join.html#parent-join) - But it is [not rdbms way](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.8/parent-join.html#_parent_join_and_performance)
2. You can filter on `sales` index and `query` back with the results from `sales` query on product collection to get product details..

To sort missing values, you should use `missing` parameter.
[Refer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#_missing_values_4)

To get ranges, `3to10, more than 30` you should use [range aggregation](aggregation range query elasticsearch)

```
GET /_search
{
    "aggs" : {
        "sale_ranges" : {
            "range" : {
                "field" : "sales",
                "ranges" : [
                    { "to" : 10 },
                    { "from" : 10, "to" : 20 },
                    { "from" : 20 }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You cannot get products without sales easily. To get that,

1. You need to get all the products from your product table
2. You need to get the products which are missing from sales table with the help of the above step.

Comment: Is there a way to combine the approach under 2) ?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to achieve in single query. @Stefan

Comment: @Stefan [Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59045460/elasticsearch-use-results-of-one-query-as-a-filter-for-another) and read comments also.

Comment: That makes sense to break up into multiple queries. But: What if i want to sort by sales ASC and those without sales at the top? I don't have data for those in the index/type without sales.

Comment: first, thanks for all your answers! But in this case, i think it wouldn't work.
The approach is like this: Aggregate all data from the sales index/type (with date in a specific range, sum all sales) and sort/filter by that and then extract the product ids from the first 50 results. The next step is to look up these IDs in the product index/type.
How will i know the IDs without any sales in the first step (remember: i'm not storing documents for 0 sales per day as this would be a waste of disk space)
Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes. You don't need to keep documents without sales in sales index. Yes you should use pagination like 50 or so. If my answer helped, could u approve.

Comment: Of course i approve :) What would you recommend to sort asc by sales (e.g. should start with sales = 0) ?

Comment: You want to sort the sales. You should use sort asc. [like this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#_sorting_numeric_fields)

Comment: That is true, but how can i find IDs with an aggregate `sales = 0`? I think this is not possible. This would be the base to find from the main index

Comment: or asked another way: how do i filter an aggregate `sales = 0` in the sales index/type and return the `product_id`s without any sales?

Comment: If you want to filter out sales 0 on aggregation, you San use `query` to filter out before doing aggregation.

Comment: Do u want to find product without sales? You can keep sales as 0 in product.

Comment: Could you maybe extend your answer so it has the workflow of two queries including being able to sort by sales and to filter by sales in a timerange (for example sales = 0, sales = 3 to 15, more than 30, etc.)? I still didn't get your comment on the filter sales = 0, how this should work?

Comment: Isn't this possible with [Aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html)?

Comment: Reason is that you don't have sale 0 products in that collection.